# How to access/export data from an azure blob container?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-application-insights

I need to access the JSON-data inside a Blob-Container. This blob contains data from a continuous export in azure.

What possibilities to access and extract that data do I have? The best solution for me would be some way to download the data and upload it to my sql-database. However, I do not know how to achieve this.

What is the best practice to access azure blob storage? Can I just use the Storage Explorer to download the data I need? Or do I have to write some code to do this?

In the end, I want to achieve something similar to the results I would get if I was using the stream-analytics service from azure.

I am aware that this post is very general and might appear like a low-effort post. But I have read up on the documentation of Application-Insights and Azure Storage and just could not find any information on how to actually get the data out of the blob-container.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated. :)

Comment: See if this helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-dot-net.

Comment: This only covers how to transfer data to Azure SQL.

Comment: I thought that's what you want. Read from blob storage and push data in SQL Server. Right?

Comment: @Maetness, not sure what do you want, but you can take a look at [Use Stream Analytics to process exported data from Application Insights](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-stream-analytics), or [Inspect the data directly from storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry#get)

Comment: I want a way to get my data out of the blob storage to my local storage. Stream Analytics is too costly I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

If the "local storage" means a local folder, you can directly use `Storage Explorer` to download the file, or [use code to download blob](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-dotnet#download-blobs).

Also, you can follow these articles to [Inspect the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry#get) and [Processing the data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/export-telemetry#processing-the-data).

Please let me know if this is what you need.